# play framework property render

Tags: playframework, playframework-2.0

I'm using play framework2, when render a field, all the content in the '_help will be rendered as text, 
e.g  `@textarea(form("operations"), '_label -> "operation",'_help ->"<p>test content</p><br><p>test content...</p>")`

after rendered, the output is:
`<p>test content</p><br><p>test content...</p>`

How can I rendered HTML code in the help property as the HTML style?

Answer (score 0):

I doesn't look like it might be possible.
I tried the normal way of rendering HTML verbatim:

```
@textarea(form("operations"), '_label -> "operation", '_help -> Html("<p>test content</p><br><p>test content...</p>"))
```

With no difference.
Might be that Play's templating engine just spits out the `toString()` of whatever is used as the `Any` as per the helpers definition:

```
def label(implicit lang: play.api.i18n.Lang): Any { ... }
```

You might have to implement your own custom tags.
[See here](https://github.com/loicdescotte/Play2-HTML5Tags) for reference.

Comment: yes, it is what in the source code： def infos(implicit lang: play.api.i18n.Lang): Seq[String] = {
      args.get('_help).map(m => Seq(m.toString)).getOrElse {
        (if (args.get('_showConstraints) match {
          case Some(false) => false
          case _ => true
        }) {
          field.constraints.map(c => play.api.i18n.Messages(c._1, c._2: _*)) ++
            field.format.map(f => play.api.i18n.Messages(f._1, f._2: _*))
        } else Nil)
      }
    }·